# How to get user activity?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-7, liferay-ide

I am trying to create a custom portlet in Liferay 7.2 that shows an activity feed of the user. I want a feed of the activity that consists of creation, updates or deletion of pages by the user logged in.

I know that we have a "Profile" widget that shows the social activity of the user, but I want to show the "site activity".

Is this possible? And if case this is possible, where should I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing out of the box for this kind of features in the community edition.

For DXP version, look at this post: https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/94584688

To implement something custom, start from here: https://github.com/amusarra/liferay-portal-security-audit